# Instead of Custom CSS Theme CSS is loading

Tags: customization, css, rewrite-rules, html5

I have some of HTML list code such as `<ul>`. after the successfull uploading the `<ul>` is linked with main stylesheet(theme css). I want to load on my custom css. But its not working

Example the css file: style.css (current loading)
                      style123.css (this stylesheet need to load on page)

Comment: How have you attempted to load style123.css? What have you tried? Share code.

Comment: My problem is that, ul style is in both stylesheet. I want to load only custom stylesheet in a particular page. code is lengthy

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to just override the styles or replace the file with a new one.

Whatever the case is, below code will help. Just wait for the best answer to your question.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_style_css_also', 99 );
function add_my_style_css_also() {  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-styles-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style123.css' );  
}
```

The code will go in your themes functions.php file.

Change /style123.css - to /folder-name/style123.css if your new file is in some folder.

In case you want to remove the parent style sheet, please use the below:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_style' );
   function remove_parent_style() {
   wp_deregister_style( 'styles' ); // or style, whatever is the handle of the sheet
}
```

You can also try the wp_deregister_style line in the 'add_my_style_css_also' function above.

Comment: The same manner only, I have done. But the both main style.css and style123.css is loading at a time. So lot of alignment problem occurs

Comment: You should use wp_dequeue_style to remove the parent style.css, you will need to use 'after_setup_theme' action hook and handle of the parent stylesheet. Updating answer.